# Angular 5: Access JSON Object with Template Syntax

Tags: json, angular

I get the following JSON represantion from a web service

```
{
   "STAT": {
      "Total": 216,
      "Average": 2.9722222222222223
   },
   "PPRP": {
      "Total": 31494,
      "Average": 19.884390677589384
   }
}
```

Within my component I have the following code:

```
  rawOverview: any
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getPlcOverview().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.rawOverview = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done loading foods')
 );
}
```

How can I access PPRP and STAT with template syntax?

I tried the following:

```
<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Tels with acks</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">PPRP</th>
      <td>{{rawOverview.PPRP?.Average}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but I get an error in the console.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'PPRP' of undefined

Is it possible to access a JSON object in this way?
Or do I have to create known objects which can access the values?

Comment: Move the question mark, so it's like this: `{{rawOverview?.PPRP?.Average}}`. Intially, `rawOverview` will be undefined, so adding the null safe operator will prevent the error

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` - why?

Comment: @tymeJV Because I get an error when I try it directly with data. JSON.parse needs a string representation. But I see now that I can assign data to my member variable directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, because rawOverview is set asynchronously, it starts life `undefined`, which is causing your error.

If you move the question mark, it will perform a null safe check, which will prevent the error

```
<td>{{rawOverview?.PPRP?.Average}}</td>
```

More on that [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can and should access it like this.
in the HTML just do something like this:

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">PPRP</th>
  <td>{{rawOverview.PPRP?.Average}}</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <th scope="row">STAT</th>
  <td>{{rawOverview.STAT?.Average}}</td>
</tr>
```